# Let the user create a list in Drupal (module?)

Tags: list, drupal, module

I'm trying to find a module for Drupal to let a user who is logged in to create his own lists (ultimately I want him to be able to drag and drop articles into a sidebar, but for now I'm just trying to put a "Add me to favorite articles" at the end of each article).

I found the Nodequeue module which is good to create lists but doesn't seem to enable personal (by each user who is logged in) lists. The smart queue user module is for Drupal 5, and I'm using Drupal 7.

Anybody's got any idea?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[flag](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://drupal.org/project/flag&ei=jmWzTsScNYHViAKLnsBu&usg=AFQjCNGRI-BYG74l8I4cf08vriYtBIc5rw&sig2=coMTfetu3Wue0raaEij8yg) should get you there